# Isotope Infinite scroll + wordpress custom type folio

Tags: wordpress, jquery-isotope, custom-post-type, infinite-scroll

I've been testing it in several variations for a week, - it still doesn't work!

1. #container height is set to 0, - why? Yep, i know, several people ask the same question, but it's no exact answer.
2. infinite scroll "works" as i use as the next link a link to page2.html form the @isotope, but "works" saying "no pages left". And does not event make any move, meeting my second page of custom post types (e.g. ... /page/2/).

All tutorials are just the same, not covering all important settings. Please, help!

P.S. My link is http://dpk-press.adwp.ru/nashi-izdaniya (if u debug and set of height=0 of #container, you'll see images, and next link, it works, all scripts are loaded...)